# Ember.TextField valueBinding to parentView

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to bind a `Ember.TextField`'s `value` to a property in it's parent view. 
This code worked prior to upgrading to the latest version of ember. I've read about the new view scoping but can't figure out if/how that applies here.

Template `my-template`:

```
    Input: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="theValue" }}
```

View:

```
App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'my-template',
    theValue: null,
    init: function(){
        this._super();
        this.set('theValue','');
    },
    keyDown: function(e){
       if(e.keyCode === 13){
            alert(this.get('theValue'));
       }
    }
});​
```

jsFiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3thg/15/)

I've tried `"parentView.theValue"` and `"view.parentView.theValue"`

I know I can give the `TextField` a `viewName` and bind to that from inside `MyView` but I want to know why the previous method stopped working.

**Update:**

- [Tom Dale's Explanation](https://gist.github.com/2494968)
- [Ember Source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L31)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've updated your jsFiddle to work: http://jsfiddle.net/U3thg/23/

I just changed your `valueBinding` to `"view.theValue"`.

```
 {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.theValue" }}
```

Answer (score 4):

To give you an answer of why the previous method stopped working.
I think the ember's team changed the bound context in the templates.
Now I think the current context is the controller attached to the enclosing view.

I derived the @ebryn fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/tcvhB/

Comment: +1 for the question, these links are very usefull, and confirm what I said. Thanks a lot.